# How to use webpack for development without webpack dev server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, webpack

I am currently using `require.js` for development so I can iterate quickly (change a file, refresh page, no build step in between), but I use `webpack` as a build tool since it is superior to `r.js`. I would like to get rid of require.js entirely and use webpack as a script loader in development. I know that's exactly what `webpack dev server` is for, but I specifically don't want to use it.

Ideally I would just include some kind of webpack loader in `<script>`, point it to my `webpack.js` build config, and let it do the job.

Comment: Have you already considered SystemJS? It's a dynamic universal loader which also can optionally do builds. https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs

Comment: Is there any documentation available? The README is pretty vague and does not cover builds/shims

Comment: That readme file does include a link about shims, but yeah, more docs would be nice. I've just started getting into it because I wanted to use the new standard ES6 module syntax in both the browser (es6-module-loader) and in node, with the ability to either compile (https://github.com/systemjs/builder) or not compile first. And to still be able to make use of any existing AMD or CommonJS module with zero modifications. Tangentially, I also found this interesting: http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to use webpack-dev-server, you could use webpack's watch functionality to keep building your script as you make changes. That will give you the workflow you're looking for. In the index.html, you'll be including your bundle only and no loader.

http://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/#watch-mode

Comment: the problem with watch is that inotify doesn't propagate to vagrant unless I use slow rsync synced folder

Comment: I'm not sure about your setup exactly, but I wouldn't run webpack-watch inside vagrant. I would run the server inside vagrant and run webpack-watch locally, and have the bundle in a volume dir.

Comment: Hey @AdamZieliński: Just saw this project on dailyjs that seems it might be helpful for you. https://www.npmjs.com/package/watch-network

Comment: running watch outside of vagrant defeats the purpose of vagrant which is to "Create and configure lightweight, reproducible, and portable development environments."; however with this watch-network thing is nice! thank you